# Can't start tomcat 5.5 on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, configuration, tomcat5.5

I can't start on my windows 2003 server machine. It's giving me the following on stderr:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:410)
```

it's driving me crazy because I've already checked environment variables, web.xml, server.xml and I can't find the source for this.

Please could anybody help?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of CATALINA_BASE in your .bat files (or environment variables) to see if they are set to an incorrect base directory--this often occurs because CATALINA_BASE gets mistakenly set to the bin subdirectory of your tomcat default installation directory.